# Over-saturated prints from Lighroom 3?

Tags: lightroom, printing, lightroom-3

I have been doing most of my printing from Photoshop lately, as I've been fine-tuning levels and using advanced sharpening techniques to eek the most out of my prints. I started working with Lightroom 3's print module again, to create custom print layouts with multiple photos. I've run into a problem where my prints are WAY too saturated compared to my perfectly calibrated screen. If I print a photo that is used in a custom print page in Photoshop, with the exact same PPI and printer profiler, it prints out fine. It seem to only be in Lightroom 3 that prints come out too saturated.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a solution?

Below is an example set of prints. The top one is from Lightroom, and the saturation and high contrast is completely obvious. The bottom one is from Photoshop. The only adjustments made to this photo were white balance, outside of that it is RAW strait out of the camera.

[image: print samples]

Comment: Sounds like a Lightroom bug, it's not reading the printer profile. I would check the Adobe forums and then submit a bug report.

Comment: I pretty much agree with Matt, it would seem like LR3 is either failing to read the printer profile or is mis-reading it in some capacity.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It is driving me up the wall. Have you found a fix already?

Comment: I have not yet found a fix, or the cause. I've updated LR3 a couple times since, and it still does this. Adobe does not seem to have any answers either. LR2 seems to print fine, so it is just limited to LR3. I've just resorted to printing from Photoshop.

Comment: Did lightroom 4 fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose the right profile? Print > Printjob > Color management & then chose the right profile, and Perceptual as a rendering intent

Comment: Yes. The printer, printer profile, and rendering intent are all correct. I have experimented with every setting combination possible, but LR3 still prints out considerably oversaturated, with clipped highlights and blocked shadows.

Comment: It's also important that if the computer is doing the color profile that the printer itself NOT be doing its own color adjustments -- these things do not compound well at all.

Comment: @Walt: I do make sure that the printer ICM is turned off. I actually have numerous saved printer setting profiles that I use that are all properly configured, and define my paper type, size, resolution, and ICM. I have double-checked that many times as well. It appears that Lightroom has a bug, and it is improperly applying my printer profiles when I print from it. No one seems to know what the problem is, so I just resort to printing from Photoshop, where I have more control anyway.